# What type of data structure is used usually for holding a lot of file info extracting from a firmware/compacked image?

Tags: c++, data-structures, extract, firmware

It's my first post and may be a naive question but I couldn't find on the internet what I wanted to know.

I want to extract files from a firmware file as well as want to keep various types of  information associated to those files such as file **name/header/file body/some sections/offset** etc which are mix type of data of binary and text and also all the files are interlinked property with other files properties like some **sections/offset/section offset** etc. Some file property info depends on other files property info so I don't know any design to complete this process by reading and processing each file sequentially or simultaneously :(

I have tried creating some class to hold those info's but I want to know what is the standard to to do this kind of file processing.This would be very great if someone please have some suggestions/links/docs or example code in **c++**.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem because it is very general. The optima strategy is very much dependent on the nature of the data, how it is structured and what you plan to do with it.

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with just reading one piece of data at a time and assembling it into the right in-memory structure as you go. Of course, lots of little reads may be slow, and the structure of the read will be obscured by the pure mass of code.

Defining a pure-data object (i.e. a `struct` in c or a `struct` or `class` with no methods in c++) for each cohesive bit of data on disk and sucking them in in one go is faster and more easily comprhended, but you will have to deal with getting the in-memory packing and endianess to match (I know you said that you're reading on the same machine that your wrote on, but still). However, this is not very "object oriented".

Or you could define a bunch of classes that know how to suck their contents off the disk. Nice and object oriented, and while the code may obscure the logic of the read it does it in little chunks with the object documentation taking up most of the slack.

Endless variations are possible.

Comment: thanks :)
some more info about this is the number of file object is more than 2,000 and it can have methods to edit the file class properties and some properties are dynamic